# Textures not downloading on IOS (Autodesk forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When opening a model in our IOS app textures fail to download at all. Any other file downloaded by the viewer is doing fine.

We have the models stored on a server that requires a login beforehand. From my investigation it looks like the session cookie is not being send along with the request compared to for example downloading an .svf file. It looks like that the threejs way of downloading the textures through an img element seems to be at fault in combination with an IOS browser.

Here are the request that are recieved by the server from a .svf file and an texture file on both ios and android.

*GET /ext-resource/bimmodel/BIMModel/Campus/Resource/3D_View/_3D_%20943569/3/mats/sitework.planting.grass.staugustine1.jpg?undefined HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8070
Origin: file://
Accept: image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,video/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/16A404 (4301299760)
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

GET /ext-resource/bimmodel/BIMModel/Campus/Resource/3D_View/*3D*%20943569/3/mats/sitework.planting.grass.staugustine.bump1.jpg?undefined HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8070
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: file://
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Lenovo TB-X704F Build/NMF26F; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=2CC77B8E5E84AD1D1AA13118E2456AD7; JSESSIONIDSSO=B27506FD26E766571D6DF7E1D7415C77
X-Requested-With: com.planonsoftware.universe

//===========================================================

GET /ext-resource/bimmodel/BIMModel/Campus/Resource/3D_View/*3D*%20943569/*3D*.svf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8070
Accept: */*
Cookie: JSESSIONID=D5D4BA8909A93C1D01733BEDF811A8BA; JSESSIONIDSSO=76F089F3D69DBD4BB562B8034D7D0FE8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/16A404 (4301299760)
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

GET /ext-resource/bimmodel/BIMModel/Campus/Resource/3D_View/*3D*%20943569/*3D*.svf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8070
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Lenovo TB-X704F Build/NMF26F; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=2CC77B8E5E84AD1D1AA13118E2456AD7; JSESSIONIDSSO=B27506FD26E766571D6DF7E1D7415C77
X-Requested-With: com.planonsoftware.universe*

Comment: could you please provide more details on the stack you're using? Are you saying that you're hosting the SVF and its related resources from your own server?

Comment: That is correct. We host the svf and all related resources on our own server. We run an wildfly/tomcat server.

Comment: I see. This scenario is not officially supported, so you'll probably need to tweak the texture loading mechanism in the Forge Viewer code based on your server/auth requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving Forge content from a custom origin is not officially supported, and the viewer always assumes that all resources are coming from Model Derivative endpoints. If you still want to serve the Forge content from your own server (and with your own auth system), you may need to tweak the texture loading process - look for `var TextureLoader = function ()` in https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/wgs.js.